# Can Visual Studio compiler errors and warnings be formatted?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, formatting, compiler-errors

Specifically, I am looking to remove namespaces from generic types. These add little value to the error message in my case, but make the error very hard to decipher.

For example an error message that says:

> VendorName.LayerName1.FolderName1.ClassName1[VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType1,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType2,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType3].Property1 cannot
>   implement
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName3.InterfaceName1[VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType1,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType2,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType3].Property1 because it
>   does not have the matching return type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[VendorName.LayerName1.FolderName1.ClassName2[VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType1,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType2,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType3],
>   VendorName.LayerName1.FolderName1.ClassName3[VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType1,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType2,
>   VendorName.LayerName2.FolderName2.GenericType3]]

would be much clearer without the namespaces:

> ClassName1[GenericType1, GenericType2, GenericType3].Property1 cannot
>   implement InterfaceName1[GenericType1, GenericType2,
>   GenericType3].Property1 because it does not have the matching return
>   type Dictionary[ClassName2[GenericType1, GenericType2, GenericType3],
>   ClassName3[GenericType1, GenericType2, GenericType3]]

Note that I have replaced "less than" and "greater than" symbols for [ and ] respectively, since the markup here does not allow me to escape these characters (at least I did not figure it out).

Is something like this possible? I am using VS2012.

Comment: You can escape the characters by using `` - like `a>b`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to remove the namespaces. I guess you either have to use shorter names or work with what you've got.